# JSONField и кириллица в django

Tags: python, django

Допустим есть у меня такой класс

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Some(models.Model):
    items = JSONField()
```

В админке например пишу {"количество": "4 шт"}, после сохранения в поле остается такое {"\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e": "4 \u0448\u0442"}. Как настроить так, чтобы отображалась кириллица?

Comment: Это безопасный формат.  Так url в вебе формируют, в отличие от iri, в котором разрешён utf-8. Только если переопределять и допиливать сам jsonfield. Можно просто обратную конвертацию сделать.

Comment: Не работайте с json на прямую. Есть хорошие варианты редакторов для таких полей. По вопросу. Это стандарт для json, если его не нарушать, то никак. Если преобразуете, то в базе у вас уже будет храниться не json, а что-то похожее.

Comment: @Igor стандарт для JSON - UTF-8, выводить кириллицу (и другие нетехнические символы) как есть вполне разрешает RFC 7159

Comment: @andreymal, согласен. Но в стандарте так же указано, что необходимо для совместимости. По редакторам, возможно использовать например https://github.com/paytm/dj-j-ka-bachcha-field, чтобы не полностью руками редактировать.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import JsonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import Some

@admin.register(Some)
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('items_prettified',)
    readonly_fields = ('items_prettified',)

    def items_prettified(self, instance):
        # Преобразуем данные поля в юникод-строку с отступами
        json_str = json.dumps(instance.items, sort_keys=True, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        # Обрезаем, если строка слишком длинная
        json_str = json_str[:5000]
        # Добавляем подсветку синтаксиса
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(style='colorful')
        output = highlight(json_str, JsonLexer(), formatter)
        style = "<style>" + formatter.get_style_defs() + "</style><br>"
        return mark_safe(style + output)
    items_prettified.allow_tags = True
    items_prettified.short_description = Some._meta.get_field('items').verbose_name.title()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться предыдущим решением, но тогда у нас будет два поля в админке: одно с кириллицей, второе в кодировке. 
Я нашел такое решение:

1. Создаём файл utils.py в папке с приложением и вставляем в него следующее:

```html
import json
from django.contrib.postgres.forms.jsonb import InvalidJSONInput, JSONField


class ReadableJSONFormField(JSONField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, InvalidJSONInput):
            return value
        return json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

2. Заходим в admins.py и "перезаписываем" поле.

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from .utils import ReadableJSONFormField
from .models import Some

@admin.register(Some)
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField: {'form_class': ReadableJSONFormField},
    }
```

Желательно именно прописывать ReadableJSONFormField в utils.py, тк если прописать в админке его, то не у меня работает через раз.